# Forming 2023 with 7s

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Idea from Ed Pegg Jr. Can you form 2023 using only the digits 7, exponentiation, modulus and factorial operations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The restrictive list of operations makes it a bit too easy:

> $$2023 \equiv 7^7 \pmod{7!}$$
>  because $7^7 = 823543 = 2023 + 163\cdot 5040  = 2023 + 163\cdot 7!$

Comment: well done you got it! I feared that adding more operations would make it too hard and give multiple answers.

Comment: actually no that's not 2023 it's only equivalent. $$ 7063 ≡7^7(mod7!) $$

Comment: Modulus is also a binary operator returning the remainder of the integer division.